# How to create a line plot using the mean of a column and extracting year from a Date column?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Update: I've now managed to solve this. For extracting the year this is what I used,

```
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).year
```

this allowed me to add a new column for the year and then use that column to plot the chart.

```
sns.lineplot(y="Class", x="year", data=df)
plt.xlabel("Year",fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel("Success Rate",fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

Now I managed the right plot chart.
[image: Final-Line Plot Chart]

I'm trying a get a line plot using the mean of a column and linking that to extracted value (year) from the date column. However, I can't seem to get the right outcome.
Here's how I extracted the Year value from the date column,

```
year=[]
def Extract_year(date):
    for i in df["Date"]:
        year.append(i.split("-")[0])
    return year
```

And here's how plotted the values to create a line plot,

```
sns.lineplot(y=df['Class'].mean(), x=Extract_year(df))
plt.xlabel("Year",fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel("Success Rate",fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

But instead of seeing a trend (see screenshot-1), it only displays a straight line (see screenshot-2) for the mean value. Could someone please explain to me, what I am doing wrong and how can I correct it?

Thanks!

[image: Expected Result]
[image: Current output]

Comment: could you provide a sample of the df?

Answer (score 0):

What you are plotting is `df['Class'].mean()`, that of course is a fixed value. I don't know which time format you're using, but maybe you need to calculate different means for different years

EDIT:
Yes there is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2020-01-20','2019-01-20','2022-01-20','2021-01-20','2012-01-20','2013-01-20','2016-01-20','2018-01-20']})
years = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.year.sort_values().tolist()
```

Comment: Class values are boolean 0 or 1. And the time format is like this, 2010-06-04. Is there a different way I can get the extracted year from the date?

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestions on how should update x on this?

sns.lineplot(y=df['Class'].mean(), x=Extract_year(df))

Comment: What I don't get is what you want to plot. `df['Class'].mean()` should be a single float, not an array